# How to make a method that accepts an array from a user, separated by ";" and adds it to the existing private array in the same class

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

Academic assignment requirements:

> Create a custom method called: appendToPersonArr with these parameters: (Person[] srcArr, int mode), that accepts an array of Person[] objects and appends it to the class' existent private array of Person[] objects.
>
> The user will be inputting the id, firstname, lastname; id, firstname, lastname;... as many times as they need to enter a new person each time. Each entry between semicolons is a different person, but each word between commas will need to be manipulated separately after
>
> No imports allowed other than for `java.util.Scanner`

I'm not sure how to put it into the array properly in that case. And I have no idea how to add this onto my private Person[] instance.

```
public class Course {
    private String courseName;
    private String courseCode;
    private String classTerm;

    private Person instructor;
    private Person[] teachAsst;
    private Person[] student;

// these are all of my private instance variables, i will need to do this adding of arrays method for both teachAsst and Student, but it will be the same process for both. 

public String appendToPersonArr(Person[] srcArr, int mode) {

    System.out.println("Enter TAs information (ID1, FirstName1, LastName1; ID2,    FirstName2, LastName2):");

    String input2 = userin.nextLine();
    String[] parts = input2.split(";");
    
    }
```

This is all I have so far for the method, and I genuinely have no idea what to do next. My desired outcome is that the users inputs get added to my existing Person[] array, and can be accessed when I need to print them out.

NOTE: I'm not allowed to use any imports other than a scanner

Comment: You might want to ask what "append" means in this context,  because I don't think of that as a standard array operation.  What might work: create a *new* array that is a big as both arrays, and copy the elements from *both* arrays into the new array.  But you can't actually extend an array in any way, so the original array is not appended but replaced.

Comment: P. S. what does `mode` do?

Comment: *"any imports"* — do you mean *imports* or do you mean *classes*?

Comment: append and mode are both words used in the instruction booklet, however I know that append meant that he wants us to store each new person added into our existing array, because later in the program we'll need to display them all. As for mode, I'm wondering the same thing, but i'm pretty sure its just the variable name he wants us to use. Not to make it too complicated but this methods will have to accept a number too because its a menu program, so that's all that the int is.

Comment: no imports like, nothing at the top other than java util scanner

Comment: "_because later in the program we'll need to display them all_" -- That's still possible if you implement what @markspace mentioned. You'd create a new array, copy the two arrays into the new array, and then reassign the field to the new array. The other option is to have an array with an allocated capacity, then maintain a "size" field. All indices in the range `[0, size)` would be non-null, anything in the range `[size, capacity)` would be null. Then you just keep copying elements from the given array to the next available spot in the "main" array.

Comment: But then you have to worry about if there is not enough capacity to append all the given elements. In that case, you'd still have to create a new, larger array, copy the elements over, and then replace the old array. However, at that point you're reimplementing `java.util.ArrayList` and so it would make more sense to just use that class instead (though that seems to be disallowed by your assignment instructions).